# performances of a continuous flow reactor

Tags: chemical-engineering

How can we know the evolution of the oulet concentration of a perfectly well-mixed continuous flow reactor taking into account the residence time distribution function called $E(t)$? I have heard about this model

$$C_{RP} = \int_0^\infty C_{RF}(t)E(t)\text{d}t$$

where

$$\begin{align}
E(t) &= \dfrac{1}{t}\exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{\tau}\right) \\
\tau &= \dfrac{V}{q}
\end{align}$$

This equation only gives the outlet concentration at the steady-state  called $C_{SS,RP}$ (so one value). I am looking for the evolution as a function of time $C_{RP}(t)$ for the concentration in a perfectly well-mixed batch reactor.

Comment: If you have updated values per second or every 5 seconds, just repeat the calculation for the new outlet concentration...

Comment: Hint: What is the difference between the time needed to reach steady state and your case to reach a *finite time*?